# WifiManager: Android

Tags: android, wifimanager

I am not able to get,

What is the purpose of Creating the MulticastLock used with WifiManager in android.

Can any body clarify me what exactly it means and when to use...

Any help much appreciated..

thanks 
rakesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IP multicast is a method for sending a packet to a group of interested receivers with only one transmission. Normal unicast requires sending the packet once per recipient.  (Broadcasting is similar to multicasting, but delivers the packet to everyone on the same subnet. With multicast, the group of receivers is 'configurable'.)

The wifi interface on Android phones will drop multicast packets automatically to save power.  Thus, if you want to be able to receive multicast packets, you need to grab the multicast lock which has the effect of telling the wifi driver to not drop multicast packets.

Only use it if you are actually joining a multicast group, e.g., using MulticastSocket instead of DatagramSocket or Socket in Java/Android.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might want to read the Android documentation on it.

But that doc doesn't say a lot, and might not be helpful, if you don't dig Multicast.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast

Multicast protocols are application-specific.  Are you just curious, or do you have an application in mind ?

Comment: i have an application that is making an use of it and very innovative application.. Have u ever worked with UPnP devices from android app. I want to make it like that... Can u help me